# How to prevent div elements from moving when border is applied to div?

Tags: html, css, border

I am currently working on a div element containing a radio button and a label. It looks like this:

[image]

When hovering over the div element,  I am applying a border to that div so the result looks like this:

[image]

The problem here is, that the moment the border is visible, you can see that the elements move 2px down and right because of the border size. The border size is 2px.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Here is the relevant css I am using:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.radioButton {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid white;
  margin: 0;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #002750;
  transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
}

.radioButton:checked {
  background-color: #002750;
}

.radioButton:focus,
.radioButton:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.15em 0.2em #0c64e7;
}

.container:focus,
.container:hover {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #419BF9;
  border-radius: 15px 5px 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="radio" class="radioButton">
  <label class="label">Copy</label>
</div>
```

I appreciate every help!

Comment: did you try to fix tnat element?

Comment: Could you provide HTML code!

Comment: Just give them a white border to start with

Comment: @mplungjan that seems kinda hacky

Comment: Please click [edit] then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Why hacky. You do not want the item to move, then don't make a difference between coloured border and not coloured border

Comment: i added some code snippet to run

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest solution is to provide a transparent border to the div that you are adding a border to when hovering.

```
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: Clean and easy. I like it

Comment: @IonicMan You called it hacky when I suggested it

Comment: I think its acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transform: translate(-2px, -2px)` to maintain it in the same position after hover

```
.container:focus, .container:hover {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #419BF9;
  border-radius: 15px 5px 5px 15px;
  transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is by adding `margin:-2px 0 0 -2px;` to `container:focus` and `containr:hover`

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.radioButton {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid white;
  margin: 0;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #002750;
  transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
}

.radioButton:checked {
  background-color: #002750;
}

.radioButton:focus,
.radioButton:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.15em 0.2em #0c64e7;
}

.container:focus,
.container:hover {
  margin:-2px 0 0 -2px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #419BF9;
  border-radius: 15px 5px 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="radio" id="btn" class="radioButton">
  <label class="label">Copy</label>
</div>
```